# Moq 'Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden' in dotnetfiddle

Tags: c#, moq, dotnetfiddle

I am trying to write a simple unittest in dotnetfiddle using Moq, but for some reason the runtime complains about security accessibility:

> Run-time exception (line 20): The type initializer for
> 'Moq.ProxyFactory' threw an exception.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while
> overriding member:
> 'Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerationOptions.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
> System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security
> accessibility of the overriding method must match the security
> accessibility of the method being overriden.]    at
> Moq.CastleProxyFactory..ctor()    at Moq.ProxyFactory..cctor()
>
> [System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Moq.ProxyFactory' threw an exception.]    at
> Moq.ProxyFactory.get_Instance()    at
> Moq.Guard.IsVisibleToProxyFactory(MethodInfo method)    at
> Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo
> method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable)    at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty)    at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty)    at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition)    at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)    at
> Unittests.Run() :line 20    at Program.Main() :line 10

I searched some other dotnetfiddles that do almost the same (like [this one](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sg2VMW)), but do not throw the error. This seems dotnetfiddle specific, because in Visual Studio this works. Do I need to set some specific .NET security flags?

```
using System;
using Moq;
using AssertLibrary;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var unittest =  new Unittests();
        unittest.Run();
    }
}

public class Unittests
{   
    public void Run()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cacheMock = new Mock<ICache>();
        cacheMock
            .Setup(c => c.GetOrSet<MyModel>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<MyModel>>()))
            .Returns((string key, Func<MyModel> captured) => { return captured(); });
        
        var stuffs = new Stuffs(cacheMock.Object);
        
        // Act
        var result = stuffs.GetModel();
        
        // Assert
        Assert.Equals(5, result.MyProperty);
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Stuffs
{
    private ICache _cache;
    
    public Stuffs(ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    
    public MyModel GetModel()
    {
        var model = _cache.GetOrSet("cache-key", () => 
                                    {
                                        return new MyModel
                                        {
                                            MyProperty = 5
                                        };
                                    });
        return model;
    }
}

public interface ICache
{
    T GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> setter);
}

public class Cache : ICache
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> setter)
    {
        // do stuff
        
        return setter();
    }
}
```

See [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EflcVb)

Comment: I'd stay away from dotnetfiddle for things like this. Why not try using a tool like LinqPad instead? That's a great program for knocking up quick demos (though to use Nuget packages, you will need to buy it)

Comment: And what is the reason to 'stay away for dotnetfiddle for things like this'? Are there a lot of known issues? Does it do some weird tricks?

Comment: These tools tend to live inside sandboxes to prevent users getting access to the system and doing weird things. I suspect the error you see here is something to do with that.